# Cannot access object values from useContext. Using useReducer and useContext for State Management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-context, use-reducer

I'm trying to access my dispatch functions as well as my states from the useContext. Weird thing is, when I try to deconstruct the context object (so I can access them directly), it tells me it doesn't exist (error Msg: Property 'authDispatch' does not exist on type '{}').

Deconstruct Method:

```
 const {authDispatch, authState, messageState, messageDispatch} = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

However, when I console.log the context WITHOUT deconstructing, I am able to see the object with the respective dispatchers/states. BUT, I cannot access those methods/states with dot notation inside of my code.

No Deconstruct:

```
const context = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

console.log(context)

```
{authState: {…}, messageState: {…}, authDispatch: ƒ, messageDispatch: ƒ}
authDispatch: ƒ ()
authState: {token: null, isAuthenticated: false, loading: true, user: null}
messageDispatch: ƒ ()
messageState: {loadedMessage: {…}, loading: true}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is my Provier.tsx file where my GlobalContext as well as my GlobalProvider are created. GlobalPrivder is indeed wrapping the entire application.

Provider.tsx

```
interface IGlobalProvider {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext({});

export const GlobalProvider: React.FC<IGlobalProvider> = ({ children }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useReducer(auth, authInitialState);
  const [messageState, messageDispatch] = useReducer(
    todaysMessage,
    todaysMessageInitialState
  );


  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        authState,
        authDispatch,
        messageState,
        messageDispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Potentially Useful Information:

- Using NextJS

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to initialize the state when creating the context

```
interface ICreateContext {
  authState: IAuthState | null,
  messageState: ITodaysMessageState | null,
  authDispatch: React.Dispatch<any>,
  messageDispatch: React.Dispatch<any>
}

const initialState = {
  authState: null,
  messageState: null,
  authDispatch: () => null,
  messageDispatch: () => null
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext<ICreateContext>(initialState);
```

But I'm still curious why I'm able to console.log the context but not access them without initializing. Does it have to do with render cycle?

Comment: Your error is just a typescript message because the type of your context was `{}`, because that's how you initialized it.